# Getting NSIndexPath from NSFetchedResultsController with entity

Tags: ios

I am using NSFetchedResultsController with my UITableView.  I have a delegate method that when a user hits Done in the detailed view, it reloads the table in the parent view.

```
- (void)addReminderViewController:(AddReminderViewController *)vc didAddReminder:(Reminder *)reminder {
    [self updateHomeView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In this block, I was wondering if I could get the NSIndexPath associated with the Reminder object from the NSFetchedResultsController somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple. If your method has access to your `NSFetchedResultsController`, all you need is this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfObject = [myNSFetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:reminder];
```

Hope this helps.